# How do I get the max value in a column and add a value to it in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble figuring out a formula to pick out the largest number in a group of numbers and then assign a value in another column.

[image]
In Column N I need to add 6500 to whichever value is the highest from F16:F27 and 0 to the rest of the values.
Can someone show me how to create a formula to do this?
Thanks!

(I added the 6500 in N21 as a place holder until I figured out the correct formula)

Comment: Why not use the formula max and then add 6500 to it?

Comment: What do you want to happen if two values are the same? Split the bonus, or both get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one in `N16` and drag it down:

```
=IF(F16=MAX($F$16:$F$27),6500,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering both of my questions!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
=IF(RANK($F16,$F$16:$F$27)=1,6500,0)
```